# How to do batch operation on Azure Storage Table?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-table-storage

I want to insert Multiple Entities into azure table Using Table Operation

I got all data as a List and I just want to save these details into table.

```
var registrationDescriptionsList = new List<RegistrationDescription>(allRegistrations);

foreach(var retrivedatafromlist in registrationDescriptionsList)
{

     batchOperation.Add(TableOperation.Insert(retrivedatafromlist));

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. Please find the code.

```
TableBatchOperation batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();

foreach (var retrivedatafromlist in registrationDescriptionsList)
{
     NotificationHubServiceBus NhsbObj = new NotificationHubServiceBus();

     var tags = "";

     foreach (var a in retrivedatafromlist.Tags)
     {
         tags = tags + a;
     }

     NhsbObj.PartitionKey = "Sample";
     NhsbObj.RowKey = retrivedatafromlist.RegistrationId;
     NhsbObj.RegistrationId = retrivedatafromlist.RegistrationId;
     NhsbObj.ExpirationDate = retrivedatafromlist.ExpirationTime.ToString();
     NhsbObj.ETag = retrivedatafromlist.ETag;
     NhsbObj.Tags = tags;

     batchOperation.Insert(NhsbObj);
}

table.ExecuteBatch(batchOperation);
```

Comment: just note that "All entities in a given batch must have the same partition key."